# centering and scaling set images in CSS - possible?

Tags: html, css, scalability, center

Hey all - I am trying to center 2 images on top of one another.  It might be more prudent that I merge these 2 images together for the sake of 'ease of use' but right now I have 2 images - the text (logo.png) and the form (form.png).  I would like them to look as such, aligned barely on top of one another - and have them centered on the screen hoping for them to scale and center according to screen size.

Is there an easy method for this that I am overlooking?  Here are my images and CSS:  (Sorry I don't have a live demo, as my sample is on a local server - but I can upload both if it might help).

The image is somewhat temporary - but the dimensions remain the same
[image]

```
 html{
    background: url(images/bg4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
    }

 #main{
     width: 875px;
     height: 350px;
     background: url(images/form.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
     position: relative;
     margin: 15% 0 0 25%;
     z-index: 1;
    }

 #main form {
     width: 1014px;
     height: 228px;
     background: url(images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
     position: absolute;
     margin: -210px 0 0 -175px;
     z-index: 2;
    }
```

With this code - I aim to center the images based on screen size, and have them scale accordingly.  It works fine on my monitor but will go off-center on my smaller laptop.

Much thanks for any help!

(Also, there is no markup currently, I have this code in a `<style type="text/css">` tag in my index.html file)

Comment: Off-topic opinion: maybe drop the word "really"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I created the layout for you.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/GeD32/

```
body{
    color:white;
}
.logo{
    background:black;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    clear:both;
}

.menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:40px auto 0px auto;
    background:gray;
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    clear:both;
}

.form{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    margin:-25px auto 0px auto;
    background:red;
     width:500px;
     height:250px;
     clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know already, but you can't count on CSS3 support, unless you happen to know all your visitors will be using a recent browser, so the background route may not be the way to go.

That being said, since you've given your `<form>` elements a fixed size and fixed top and left margin, they will of course shift when the viewport is a different size. FYI, since you made them absolute positioned, you can use the `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` attributes instead of margin, i.e. `top: -210px;` and `left:-175px;`

If you want #main centered horizontally, use the auto value for the left and right values:

```
margin: 15% auto <<whatever_bottom_should_be>>
```

or

`margin: 15% auto;` -> top and bottom the same value, left and right the same value

That will tell the browser to split the available space equally to both side margins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them centered, you could use:

html{
 width: 100%;
 margin:0px auto;
}

#main{
 width: 875px;
 height: 350px;
 background: url(images/form.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
 margin:0px auto;
 z-index: 1;
}

#main form {
 width: 1014px;
 height: 228px;
 background: url(images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
 margin: 0px auto;
 z-index: 2;
}

However, let us know if that was what you were after. Usually this setting would work fine if they were two different div tags.

Comment: hmmm, this seems to move the logo and the form together if I change the margin on one or the other...the logo seems to be 'attached' to the form.